# How do I convert my Csv file to right format?

Tags: python, csv, formatting

When I read and print the CSV file I downloaded, then I got the following results[image]

As you can see, the result is printed in a wired format. 
If I want to print a specific column, here is the error message I got.

[image]

I believe the format of the winedata.csv file is wrong, because my code works for other csv file. How do I convert my csv file to right format?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots. You should paste your code and output as text.

Comment: When reading from CSV, you did not specify the separator, which means "," is assumed. Hence you only have one column at the moment. Your should use the `sep` option to `pd.read_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `winedata.csv` file is separated by semi-colons, rather than commas. Therefore, you need to provide the `sep` option to `pd.read_csv` as follows:

```
wine_data = pd.read_csv("winedata.csv", sep=";")
```

You will then be able to access your `pH` column as:

```
wine_data["pH"]
```

Comment: @XuanRen Great. Please consider accepting my answer so that we can remove this question from the unanswered pile.